# To display a table and dropdown list from database, Django SQL database

Tags: mysql, django, listview, dropdown

This is what I currently have, the **first dropdown is faculty**, **second is the module**. This is created with ajax.

Now, **I would like to create a seperate table** that shows all the modules and their respective details when I select a specific faculty. Let's say I selected Physics the table content will now show all the modules and their semester availability and credit unit. **The dropdown and the content of the table have to be dynamic and change according to what is selected.**

The model would contain column faculty, modules, semester availability, and credit unit.

*I would appreciate any resources that will guide me in this! Thank you!*

Comment: you can implement a dependent dropdown with AJAX...please refer to this article and develop according to your requirementnt.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: hi thank you! i have created an ajax dropdown and would now like to proceed to create a table that is linked to this drop-down, im not sure how do i proceed with this.